# Use asynchonous tasks with INavigationAware with Prism

Tags: c#, prism, prism-6

How to call an `async` method into a method that implements an interface when this method is NOT `async`?

In my ViewModel, I've got an `async` method that should be executed each time the user navigates into the view.

The fastest (bad) solution I was able to find is this one

```
public class MyViewModel : INavigationAware
{
    //[...]
    public async void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationContext navigationContext)
    {
        await Refresh();
    }
    public async Task Refresh()
    {
        await Task.Run(() => 
        {
           // Asynchronous work
        });
        /* Actions on Gui Thread */           
    }
    //[...]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work for this, based on what I can gather from the question. I did a quick test with a project I am working on to see the concept work. The `Refresh` method should run each time you navigate to the view using this view model.

```
public class MyViewModel : INavigationAware
{
    //[...]
    public void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationContext navigationContext)
    {
        Refresh();
    }
    public async void Refresh()
    {
        await Task.Run(() => 
        {
           // Asynchronous work
        }).ContinueWith(t=> /* Actions on Gui Thread */, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());            
    }
    //[...]
}
```

I removed the `async/await` on the `OnNavigatedTo`, and had that call an `async` `Refresh` method that returns nothing.